# How do I write a Route::resource in Laravel 8?

Tags: laravel

I'm pretty new to Laravel; I was dabbling a bit with Laravel 7.x back in the spring but I'm now running Laravel 8.x. I'm imitating the coding that is being done in a YouTube course on coding Laravel and Vue but I'm having trouble with a Route::resource that the instructor uses. He's running Laravel 7.x and I know the syntax changed some for Laravel 8.x. I've looked for examples online and even found one for Laravel 8.x but it didn't actually work. Here's my best guess, which also fails to work.

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\ToDoController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::resource('todo', ToDoController::class);
```

Can anyone tell me what I have to change or at least point me to some examples that actually work?

Edit:
In response to the comments, this is the exact code I'm executing and it doesn't work. I still get the Http status code 500 (Internal Server Error). Initially, Firefox would actually give me a bunch of information in the Response tab to flesh out what the error was. The last several times I've tried it though, all of the tabs in the XHR are simple EMPTY. Devtools in Chrome also gives me nothing. There's nothing in new Laravel.log either. I just assumed I had messed up the syntax for the Route. Now I have no idea what to do to get past this problem other than maybe learning Postman so that I can get more details out of it.

Edit 2:
My apologies for misunderstanding the log. From glancing at it earlier in the day, I had the impression that the first entries in the log were the latest ones; since the first entries hadn't changed, I thought nothing had been written to the Laravel.log either. Obviously, the reverse is true. Looking at it now, I see several identical log entries that identify the problem but not in a way I understand. Here's the most recent one:

```
[2020-12-05 21:59:19] local.ERROR: Use of undefined constant console - assumed 'console' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Use of undefined constant console - assumed 'console' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) at C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ToDoController.php:38)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\ToDoController.php(38): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Use of undefine...', 'C:\\\\Laravel\\\\Lara...', 38, Array)
#1 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): App\\Http\\Controllers\\ToDoController->store(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#2 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('store', Array)
#3 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(254): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\ToDoController), 'store')
#4 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(197): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#5 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(692): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#6 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#7 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#9 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php(127): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#10 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php(103): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), Array)
#11 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests.php(55): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 'api', Object(Closure))
#12 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure), 'api')
#13 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(694): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#15 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(669): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#16 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(635): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#17 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(624): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(166): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#19 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(128): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#24 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#25 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#26 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(87): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\fruitcake\\laravel-cors\\src\\HandleCors.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fruitcake\\Cors\\HandleCors->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#30 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#32 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustHosts.php(48): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(167): Illuminate\\Http\\Middleware\\TrustHosts->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#34 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(103): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#35 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(141): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#36 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(110): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\public\\index.php(52): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#38 C:\\Laravel\\LaraVue_CRUD02\\server.php(21): require_once('C:\\\\Laravel\\\\Lara...')
#39 {main}
"}
```

As with virtually EVERY Laravel stacktrace I've ever seen - Java was very different! - NONE of the lines in the Laravel stacktrace ever seems to point to a line of the code *I* wrote, just modules that already existed, generated by Laravel, and which I never touched. That makes it *much* harder to figure out where my mistake is. If anyone can enlighten me on how to interpret a Laravel stacktrace, I'd be deeply grateful!

And, of course, I want to understand what its issue is with "console". The only time I've written that word in this project is in statements like this:

```
console.log("ToDoComponent mounted");
```

That *is* permissible in Laravel isn't it? It was the standard way of seeing what was going on in Vue programs that didn't use Laravel so I assumed it would work in components running in Laravel.

Edit 3:

So it turns out I shot myself in the foot by thinking it was okay to use console.log() statements when that is not okay in Laravel. I truly didn't know that. It works in Vue so I (foolishly) assumed it would work in Vue within Laravel. Okay then, I went back to the Laravel docs and found this:

```
Log::debug('An informational message.');
```

I thought that must be what I'd need to do in Vue components in Laravel so I tried replacing one of my console.log() statements with a Log::debug() but VS Code doesn't like that, at least in a Vue component. It didn't like  either, leaving the question of how I can write to the log in Vue components in Laravel. Maybe you can answer that along the way, otherwise I'll research that separately.

Here's my ToDoController, as requested. As you can see, I've only touched the store() method; the others are later in the course:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\ToDo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ToDoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        console.log("ToDoController.store() started");
        ToDo::create($request->all());
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\ToDo  $toDo
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy(ToDo $toDo)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I really appreciate your patience as this noob tries to understand Laravel better.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "which also fails to work". Your route resource syntax is correct. What is the issue/error you are facing?

Comment: @Donkarnash -  I was on a break from my meeting when I posted this but the meeting has resumed (via Skype) so they're all jabbering behind me and it's too distracting to write now. I'll post again when the meeting is over between 4:30 and 5 EST.

Comment: If you're upgrading the project you wrote before on Laravel 7 then the route declarations will be the same as Laravel 7. Only if you're using the latest Laravel 8 boilerplate will you need to declare the controllers using their fully qualified name (what you're doing here).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code. Have you tried using it?

Comment: @miken32 - Yes, I have. I've edited the question to describe how it failed.

Comment: You are defining these routes for an API client, yes? Because of course routes for a web client would go in `web.php`.

Comment: @mikem32 - You're right. I misread the log. I had the impression that the oldest entries were at the bottom but the reverse is true. I'm editing the question again to post the error I'm getting.

Comment: @mikem32 - Honestly, I'm not sure if it's a web client or an API client. I'm following the instructions in this video as the guy builds a program in Laravel that also uses Vue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hbq2CAHNRZM. I've gotten up to minute 32 but then the wheels fall off.

Comment: Are you accessing it with a web browser? If yes, your routes should be in `web.php`.

Comment: What does the log have for the 500 server error

Comment: `console.log` is javascript command not PHP so the error. Pls post the code for ToDoController

Comment: @miken32 - Yes, I'm using a web browser to look at it. He puts the route in api.php and comments after the video are reporting mixed results: some say it doesn't work in Laravel 8 but others, presumably more experienced, say it IS working but you have to make a few changes along the way - but most of those changes are not detailed.

Comment: `console.log` is JavaScript, not PHP. Just put your routes in `web.php` unless you are building an API. This is nothing to do with Laravel 8. Every route in `api.php` will have `/api/` as a URL prefix, and it is intended for a specific purpose.

Comment: @Henry Have removed the answer as it was not a direct answer to your question. However you can find the details at https://gist.github.com/thinkstudeo/adf98d0ec800e5d0a62ef7a772f9ff33

Comment: `console.log` is javascript so you can't have it in PHP. Something similar is `dump("ToDoController.store() started")` . Similarly Vue components are javascript so you can't have PHP methods in it `Log::debug()` You still need to remove the `console.log()` from your store method. And as @miken32 has suggested you should move your `Route::resource()` to `routes/web.php`

Comment: Thanks for telling me about dump(); that's a new one on me. I had just started researching and hadn't found anything yet that was equivalent to console.log(). As for my app, I've moved my routes to web.php but it still doesn't work. This time I get a 404 but there's nothing in Firefox, Chrome or laravel.log that elaborates on what it isn't finding. This is really getting frustrating.